# error while building mysqlclient on windows

Tags: python, mysql, django

everyone ! I am facing the below issue when I ran the command : `python setup.py build` inside the mysqlclient directory. I have installed mysqlclient 1.3.7

Do you have any solution to fix this ?  I am trying to setup MySQL with django.

---

```
C:\Users\Hp\Downloads\Compressed\mysqlclient-1.3.7\mysqlclient-1.3.7>python setu
p.py build
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,3,7,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.7 "-IC
:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -IC:\Python34\include
 -IC:\Python34\include /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\_mysql.obj /Z
l
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'my_config.h': No su
ch file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\
cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

C:\Users\Hp\Downloads\Compressed\mysqlclient-1.3.7\mysqlclient-1.3.7>python setu
p.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing top-level names to mysqlclient.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to mysqlclient.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing mysqlclient.egg-info\PKG-INFO
reading manifest file 'mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
 /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,3,7,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.7 "-IC
:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -IC:\Python34\include
 -IC:\Python34\include /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\_mysql.obj /Z
l
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'my_config.h': No su
ch file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\
cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it via pip

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

If you want to build it from source you need to get mysql source as well. Follow [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-source-build.html) link to find proper source to download.

Comment: Anything else we can try ?

Comment: What's your pip version? Make sure use the latest one.

Comment: pip 7.1.2 and this is the latest one